# Address the same group of CSS selectors on each breakpoint. How to keep the CSS DRY?

Tags: css, optimization, sass, css-selectors, breakpoints

I've been writing CSS (SASS) for several years now and would say that I'm quite proficient at it. However, I can't think of a good alternative for the following code.

My SASS right now, somewhat simplified for Stackoverflow:

```
.container {
  &.-left {
    h1, 
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6,
    p,
    ul,
    ol {
      left: 0;
    }
  }

  &.-right {
    h1, 
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6,
    p,
    ul,
    ol {
      right: 0;
    }
  }
}



@include breakpoint(small) {
  .container {
    &.-left {
      h1, 
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6,
      p,
      ul,
      ol {
        left: 10px;
      }
    }

    &.-right {
      h1, 
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6,
      p,
      ul,
      ol {
        right: 10px;
      }
    }
  }
}



@include breakpoint(medium) {
  .container {
    &.-left {
      h1, 
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6,
      p,
      ul,
      ol {
        left: 20px;
      }
    }

    &.-right {
      h1, 
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6,
      p,
      ul,
      ol {
        right: 20px;
      }
    }
  }
}



@include breakpoint(large) {
  .container {
    &.-left {
      h1, 
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6,
      p,
      ul,
      ol {
        left: 30px;
      }
    }

    &.-right {
      h1, 
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6,
      p,
      ul,
      ol {
        right: 30px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how, but I think that the code could be written in a more elegant way. It feels very cumbersome to list and address the same group of selectors multiple times for each breakpoint. Do you have an idea how I could shorten this code and make it more readable? I suppose with CSS variables or SASS functions?

Comment: Do you need to optimize only the `h1, h2, h3...` selectors or the whole `.container, &.-right, &.-left, h1, h2...` selectors group? And are `left` and `right` properties the only ones you need to put into `&.-left` and `&.-right`? Are they always the same value?

Comment: I only want/need to optimize the h1, h2, h3 ... part. And no, `left` and `right` aren't the only properties I have to set. I just simplified my the example code.

Comment: Ok, I undeleted my answer, is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. With a mixin

You can use a `@mixin` to store the selectors and then `@include` it where you need:

```
@mixin defaultSelectors() {
  & {
    h1, 
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6,
    p,
    ul,
    ol {
      @content;
    }
  }
}

.container {
  &.-left {
    @include defaultSelectors {
      left: 0;
    }
  }

  &.-right {
    @include defaultSelectors {
      right: 0;
    }
  }
}

[...]
```

---

#### 2. With a variable

You can also store the selectors in a variable as a list and then use [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation):

```
$defaultSelectors: h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol;

.container {
  &.-left {
    #{$defaultSelectors} {
      left: 0;
    }
  }

  &.-right {
    #{$defaultSelectors} {
      right: 0;
    }
  }
}

[...]
```

Comment: Thank you, the mixin solution is pretty much what I was looking for ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the *include* inside the other selector like this:

```
.container {
  &.-left {
    h1, 
    h2 {
      left: 0;

      @include breakpoint(small) {
        left: 10px;
      }
      @include breakpoint(medium) {
        left: 20px;
      }
    }
  }

  &.-right {
    h1, 
    h2 {
      right: 0;

      @include breakpoint(small) {
        right: 10px;
      }
      @include breakpoint(medium) {
        right: 20px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. That might do to trick. But as I stated in my question, I somewhat simplified the code in my example. In reality I have to set way more properties than only `left` and `right`. That would mean I have to include the different breakpoints a couple times across my file. Which in the end would not really lead to a leaner (and shorter) solution.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with the multiple properties, you can set more than one property per rule.  Maybe we need a bit more information ?